# What is the right way to implement descriptors in Python 3.6+?

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-descriptors

In Raymond Hettingers [Mental Game on YouTube](https://youtu.be/UANN2Eu6ZnM?t=2812):

```py
class Validator:

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.private_name = f'_{name}'    

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return getattr(obj, self.private_name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        self.validate(value)
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)
```

Daw-Ran Liou states in [Writing descriptors in Python 3.6+](https://dev.to/dawranliou/writing-descriptors-in-python-36):

> [...] instead of using builtin function getattr and setattr, we need to reach into the **dict** object directly, because the builtins would be intercepted by the descriptor protocols too and cause the RecursionError.

```py
class Validator:

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name= name
    
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return obj.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        self.validate(value)
        obj.__dict__[self.name] = value
```

But Matthew Egans [Describing Descriptors on YouTube](https://youtu.be/lmcgtUw5djw?t=1141) says:

```py
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

class Validator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = WeakKeyDictionary()

    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        return self.data[obj]

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        self.validate(value)
        self.data[obj] = value
```

What would be the correct way to implement descriptors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is fine. All three are valid implementations.

Not sure why the second author says you can't use `getattr` in that way. Yes, `getattr` invokes the descriptor protocol, but the descriptor is being assigned to `type(obj).__dict__[name]` but you set `private_name` as `f'_{name}'` so there won't be any infinite recursion... It *would* if you used `self.private_name = name` in `__set_name__` instead of `self.private_name = f'_{name}'`, but that isn't what either of the first two are doing...

EDIT: reading that link, that is what the author is doing...

That being said, the second solution isn't *incorrect*.

As to the third solution, I surmise that this is an alternative, which doesn't pollute the instances namespace at all, keeping a separate namespace -- the `WeakKeyDictionary`. Not a bad idea, but it isn't any more "correct" than the other two. Note, it *does* assume the the class hashes based on identity, which isn't the case. You can implement `__hash__` in a class to hash based on something else, which is fine if your class is "conceptually" immutable, e.g. some `Point(x, y)` class which doesnt' expose any mutator methods, and that hashes based on the values of `x` and `y`. So, that would make this approach a little more restrictive, but otherwise, it's a clever solution to not messing with the instances namespace.

I'd opine that the first is the most Pythonic in the sense that it is idiomatic. But again, all three are valid solutions.

Comment: I was trying to apply the concepts of all authors to the same example (from Raymond Hettinger) and wrote `self.private_name = f'_{name}'` instead of `self.name = name`. I'll change it.

Comment: In my opinion it's not polluting the instance's namespace, it _belongs_ to the instance. Is there any path to manually lookup the data stored in **WeakKeyDictionary()** from the instance via dotted notation? Thanks.

Comment: @Agent49  huh? I said the whole point is to *avoid* polluting the instance namespace, like the normal way with `_some_attribute`. And note, *it doesn't belong to the instance*, descriptors belong to the class. Anyway, to get to a descriptor, you need something like `type(instance).__dict__['Validator'].data`

Comment: I know. As you pointed  out, (1) without _WeakKeyDictionary_ attributes are stored in the instances' namespace and accessible via `obj_instance.__dict__.[_my_attrib]`. (2) With _WeakKeyDictionary_, they're not. However, since _my_attrib_ belongs to the instance I don't see any reason yet why using _WeakKeyDictionary_ here. I know that descriptors belong to the class not the instance. The dotted lookup-order (also on instances) says to lookup `type(instance).__dict__['my_attrib']` if it is a data-descriptor.